# General Steinitz exchange lemma- Proof Help

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

I've been trying to find a proof of the Steinitz exchange lemma (the general one, not the one for finite bases).

The closest I've found is the proof given here:

[General Steinitz exchange lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998876/general-steinitz-exchange-lemma)

> Let $B$ be a basis of a vector space $V$, and $L\subset V$ be linearly independent. Then there is an injection $j:L\rightarrow B$ such that $L\cup(B\setminus j(L))$ is a disjoint union and a basis of the vector space $V$.

with solution:

> Let $\mathcal L$ denote the set of all pairs $(L',j)$ such that $L'\subseteq L$ and $j:L'\to B$ an injection satisfying that $L'\cup(B\setminus j(L'))$ is a disjoint union and a basis of the vector space $V$. Define a partial order $\preceq$ on $\mathcal L$ by $(L_1,j_1)\preceq(L_2,j_2)$ iff $L_1\subseteq L_2$ and $j_{2\mid L_1}=j_1$. Note that a subset $S$ of $V$ is linearly independent iff every finite subset of $S$ is linearly independent, and generating set iff every element of $V$ is generated by a finite subset of $S$. Therefore it's it's easy to see that every sub-chain of $\mathcal L$ admits a maximal element in $\mathcal L$. Then applying Zorn's Lemma we reach the conclusion.

I can just about follow it, it looks like for a given chain a max element for a particular chain could be made by taking the union $M$ of all the first elements of each member of the chain and the (unique) $m$ function that agrees with all the second elements of each member of the chain. I can prove this max $(M,m)$ is such that $M\cup B\setminus m(M)$ is a disjoint union and linearly independent but can't seem to prove it spans $V$, and is thus in $\mathcal L$, so I can't yet apply zorns' lemma and finish the proof.

can someone please provide a explanation as to why or if I have gone wrong an explanation as to where.

Note: new question and not comment on original question because I lack the points to ask the question as a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right to be stuck: this proof is incorrect.  For instance, suppose $B=\{b_0,b_1,b_2,\dots\}$.  You can then one-by-one replace elements of this basis: first replace $b_0$ by $b_0-b_1$, then replace $b_1$ by $b_1-b_2$, then replace $b_2$ by $b_2-b_3$, and so on.  At each finite stage of this, you still have a basis, but in the limit you get the set $L=\{b_0-b_1,b_1-b_2,b_2-b_3,\dots\}$ which does not span the entire space.  This then gives a chain in $\mathcal{L}$ that has no upper bound.

Here is a correct proof.  Let $C\subseteq B$ be a maximal subset of $B$ with the property that $C\cup L$ is linearly independent (such a $C$ exists by Zorn's lemma).  By maximality, the span of $C\cup L$ must contain every element of $B$ and this is all of $V$, so $C\cup L$ is a basis.  To finish the proof, we just need to know that $|B\setminus C|=|L|$ so we can choose an injection $j:L\to B$ with image $B\setminus C$.  To prove this, note that $|B\setminus C|$ and $|L|$ are both the dimension of the vector space $V/\operatorname{span}(C)$, since the images of $B\setminus C$ and $L$ are each bases for this vector space.

[Note that the fact that any two bases of an infinite-dimensional vector space have the same cardinality can be proven quite easily without the Steinitz exchange lemma.  If $B$ and $B'$ are both infinite bases, then each element of $B$ is in the span of finitely many elements of $B'$, so you need at most $|B|\cdot \aleph_0=|B|$ elements of $B'$ to span all of $B$.  Since $B'$ is a basis, this means $|B'|\leq |B|$.  Similarly, $|B|\leq|B'|$ as well, so $|B|=|B'|$.]

Comment: But does the assertion have an easy proof $|B| \cdot \aleph_0 = |B|$? Don't you need a non-trivial axiom of choice argument for it?

Comment: Yes, that requires the axiom of choice.  But that is a general well-known fact about cardinal arithmetic that doesn't have to do with linear algebra specifically.

Comment: I hope you understand I didn't intend to criticize your answer. It's just I have been looking/hoping for a more self-contained proof that uses Zorn or well-ordering in a straightforward way, without needing to invoke non-trivial facts about cardinal arithmetic. I understand the fact is quite standard in the theory of cardinal arithmetic, but my concern is that a student who has not taken a course dedicated to set theory would probably not have seen it, except in the case $|B|=\aleph_0$.

Comment: That's fair.  I'm actually not sure where that fact would be covered in a typical undergraduate curriculum.  I learned it in my pointset topology class.

Comment: I think the Steinitz lemma is ususually used to prove that any two bases have the same cardinality, a result which you use. There must be a better proof.

Comment: @Bernie: The Steinitz lemma is used to prove that fact for _finite-dimensional_ vector spaces.  It is not useful for proving it for infinite-dimensional vector spaces, where instead it is easier to prove that any two bases have the same cardinality by other means, and then use that to prove the Steinitz lemma.